# Dynamic textLimit in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to create notepad with checkboxes in my Compose app
It requires a LazyColumn with multiple TextFields.

To do that I require somehow limit words in app to measured width

Could someone help me measure how many words I can limit to ,dynamiclly by view width

```
    @Composable
    fun NoteField(
        modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
        textLimit: Int = 30
    ) {
        val focusManager = LocalFocusManager.current
    
        var text by remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue("")) }
        TextField(
            modifier = modifier,
            value = text,
            onValueChange = {
                if (it.text.length <= textLimit) text = it
                else focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
            },
            placeholder = { Text(stringResource(id = R.string.search)) },
            colors = TextFieldDefaults.textFieldColors(
                textColor = Theme.colors.Text,
                disabledTextColor = Color.Transparent,
                backgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
                focusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                unfocusedIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent,
                disabledIndicatorColor = Color.Transparent
            ),
            maxLines = 1,
            keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions(imeAction = ImeAction.Next),
            keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                onNext = {
                    focusManager.moveFocus(FocusDirection.Down)
                }
            )
        )
    }
```

Comment: What does it mean *how many words* ? Words can have different length.

Comment: Letters, my bad, but you're missing my point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do yo want to limit your checkbox list to ONE line and then move to next line with a a checkbox when text overflows?

If you want that you could just use overflow to ellipsis when text fills the width of the screen.
But I don’t think that is what you want.

I think you should just remove maxLines = 1 and let the textfield expand down on its own, what would be the problem with that?

EDIT!
You can also do something like this to use onTextLayout, then you can check for overflow.
For demonstration purposes I kept Text box and input field in a `Column`, than can be solved by adding them on top each other in a `Box`(or whatever floats your boat).

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TextFieldWithOverflowDetection() {

  val red = Color(0xFFe30613)
  val white = Color(0xFFFFFFFF)
  var value by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
  var bgColor by remember { mutableStateOf(white) }
  BasicTextField(
    value = value,
    onValueChange = { value = it },
    modifier = Modifier
      .background(white)
      .fillMaxWidth(),
    decorationBox = { innerTextField ->

      Column { // change to e.g Box to overlap text and innerTextField
        Text(
          text = value,
          maxLines = 1,
          overflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
          modifier = Modifier
            .background(bgColor)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
          onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
            bgColor = if (textLayoutResult.hasVisualOverflow) red else white
          },
        )
        innerTextField()
      }
    },
  )
}
```

Comment: I wanted to limit to one line ,and remove expanding from it.

Comment: Ok, in that case you could use onTextLayout, there you can detect overflow and act upon it.
You need to change to BasicTextField instead of TextField (don't worry about the UI, you can do whatever you need on decorationBox).

See this blog post for instance:
https://proandroiddev.com/detect-text-overflow-in-jetpack-compose-56c0b83da5a5

Comment: Thanks, I tried to recreate textfield by passing onTextField